# Show Error is User Enter Special Character in Textbox Angular Js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to AngularJs. I have an input field and i want to show the red line error and restrict the user if user enter the special character in Textbox.

here is my Html

```
<input data-toggle="password" class="form-control" data-placement="after" type="password"
                           placeholder="User Name"
                           ng-model="obj.username" maxlength="16" style="text-transform: lowercase"/>
```

I want to restrict the user and show the error "Special Character are not allow please Try Another one" and also restrict the user.. How can i handle this in Controller

Comment: use `ng-change="change()"` event handle on your input box and in controll write your change method to test your input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have two possible solutions for you:

1. Simply use the HTML input pattern attribute, in this way you can disallow anything you want from being submitted, with native HTML validation.

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$" />
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

2. Create a method with angular, that validates the input, on each change event.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('myController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.input = "";
      $scope.error = false;
      
      // Validation function, that sets error=true, if special chars in input.
      $scope.validForm = function() {
        var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$");
        if (!regex.test($scope.input)) {
            $scope.error = true;
            console.log("true");
        } else {
            $scope.error = false;
           console.log("false");
        }
      }
      
      // Validation on each input change
      $scope.change = function() {
        $scope.validForm();
      };
      
      // Initial validation
      $scope.validForm();
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">
  <form ng-controller="myController">
  
    <!-- Input with change function that triggers validation -->
    <input type="text" ng-model="input" ng-change="change()">

    <!-- Error message shown if validation has errors -->
    <div ng-show="error">
      Error! Please fill and don't use special chars!
    </div>

    <!-- Disabled submit if validation has errors -->
    <div>
      <button ng-disabled="error">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```